# How can I hide a form after submission?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I was wondering how can I hide a form after submission. I tried something with JavaScript, but I keep getting a message from the form that no file was chosen.

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('#files').remove();
    });
</script>
<form id="files" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: $('#files').hide(); or $('#files').remove();

Comment: Its not an input element its a button, your selector must be $('button[type="submit"]'). But i recommend you, wait till submit request completed and then remove the form.

Comment: Did that...still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you struggle to get the button element with `jQuery`. Assign an `id` to your button like:

```
<button id="mybutton" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

And adjust your `javascript` to get the element by its id:

```
$(function() {
    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        $("#files").remove();
    });
});
```

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function
>   document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient.

Also, you need to wrap the `click` event handler inside the [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

---

I do not recommended to remove the form on button click. How could you be certain that the data has been submitted and processed? One solution would be to take advantage of the [`success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url) to redirect the user to another page, but only when the form is successfully processed by the back end.

Comment: This indeed worked. But is there any way to hide it permanently after submission ? On page refresh it will show again.

Comment: If you want to allow a user only to fill in and send a form once you would need to put that logic on the server side. Check for the information if the current user has already submitted a form in your ``views.py`` and only pass the ``form`` variable to the render context if he has not.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the `id`, so use it.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    $('#files').remove();
});
```

Comment: The form is still there. And I still get message with 'No file chosen.'